# Python - Beautifulsoup - looping divs tags with same class names

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm wondering how to scrap information off a website where there is multiple elements that have the same identifiers from which I want to scrap price data from. The issue I'm having is that when I loop through each div and print() I see its pasted multiple times in the console. I assume this is du to the div I'm locating encapsulated multiple elements with the same tag + classname.

[HTML Page notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYEUx.png)

```
GraphicPrice = soup.findAll('div', class_='col')

for price in GraphicPrice:
    prices = price.find('span', class_='price__amount')
    if prices is None:
        pass
    else:
        print(prices.text)
```

Output:

```
£859.99
£859.99
£1,049.99
£1,049.99
£829.99
£829.99
£899.99
£899.99
£999.95
£999.95
£999.95
£999.95
```

What I want is to eliminate the duplicate information and understand how to refactor my code to prevent this from happening.

I want every elements on the page prices to be printed. Currently I get the prices but it's duplicated 3 times.

Any help would be appreciated. (I'm still leaning)  :)

Answer (score 2):

first, you scrap all div tags with "col" class

```
soup.findAll('div', class_='col')
```

this div tag has one span class and that one class has two other nested span tags.

so, if you code like this

```
price.find('span', class_='price__amount')
```

it scraps two span tags with "price_amount" on each div tag.
that represents a wrong class.

if you want a second span tag then your code is like this.

```
soup.findAll('span', class_='price--sale--colored').find('span', class_='price__amount')
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I actually got some errors which failed to produce any prices.

My implementation, as you suggest, finds all the div tags with 'col' but the problem is inside this div tag, there is 2 more div tags with 'col' as an attribute. How do I loop the outer div 'col' to get each product element on the page while looping the inner div 'col' for the price amounts for each.

I hope that make sense or if you want more info let me know.

Comment: if possible please give link that website and which price you want to fetch.

Comment: Sure, here's the pages I'm trying to scrape : https://www.overclockers.co.uk/pc-components/graphics-cards/nvidia-graphics-cards/nvidia-geforce-rtx-3080

Answer (score 0):

Use `.select('span')` to get object from inner of the selected object like

```
GraphicPrice = soup.findAll('div', class_='col')

for price in GraphicPrice:
    prices = price.select('span')
```